# Parse JSON String into raw Java types using Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I would like to parse some JSON string the represents either an array or a map in the simplest possible way. I have the whole JSON string, no streaming is needed.

What I would like to do is something as similar as possible to this:

```
Object obj = parseJSON(theString);
```

Where obj would then hold an instance of either a Map or a List (I cannot know in advance which). The JSON object can be arbitrarily nested with maps and arrays but all types will be representable as basic Java types: String, Integer, Double, Boolean plus Map and ArrayList, nothing else.

All the simple examples I have found so far require me to know what the type is and which types I want, but I want to let all this do the JSON parser since I simply will not know in advance what I get.

If Jackson is not the best library to do this, what else could I use?

Comment: Go to json.org and pick a kit from about 20 for Java.

Comment: (I see lots of Java folks struggling with simple JSON problems because they're all so enamored of Jackson and it's clones.)

Comment: I'm so enamored with Jackson it hurts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option should you decide to ditch Jackson (Jackson is fine, I'm quite agnostic in the JSON wars) is [json-simple.](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/)

```
JSONObject jObject = JSONValue.parse(String jsonString);
```

Since JSONObject extends java.util.HashMap everything should work.

Comment: No, because if the JSON string represents an array I want a list in that case. As I found out a few seconds after posting,  readValue(theString, Object.class) will do this: it will give me an ArrayList if JSON is an Array and a LinkedHashMap if the JSON is a map.

Comment: I guess my question is "then what"?  You have an Object that is either a Map or a List, but what can you do with it?  You gonna do an instanceof?  Guess I don't completely understand your question...

Answer (score 5):

All you need to do is this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String,Object> map = mapper.readValue(theString, Map.class);
```

I'm pretty sure this returns a `LinkedHashMap`, if you care.

And in my opinion, you won't find a better serializer/deserializer for Java <-> JSON than Jackson. But there are many others like [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

Comment: The problem I had been struggling with was that I only saw examples where one had to specify, like in your example, Map or Array or my own types. I was too silly to see that I can actually just specify Object.class instead and it will do exactly what I want.

Comment: Oh yes, you can do that too. I thought you wanted to be explicit about using a `Map`. But `Object` works.

Answer (score 2):

Silly question, simple answer:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Object obj = mapper.readValue(theString, Object.class);
```

That seems to do exactly what I want. And it's so obvious too!